# Issue with signing app with wildcard profile

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, provisioning-profile

I developed an iPad application to a client. My client has Apple Enterprise license. But they dont allow me to sign the app with their certificate. They just ask me to provide .xarchive file so that they can sign the app and create the ipa file.
This is how I have done that

```
1. Create a appid with com.mycompany.myapp.abc
2. Create a adhoc profile using above appid with my developer portal
3. set the bundle ID of my app com.mycompany.myapp.abc
4. Set the code signing identity to above profile in my app's target
5. archive the file using xcode 4.6.1
6. export the xarchive file and send to the client
7. Ask client to create a inhouse Dis profile with com.mycompany.myapp.* appid
8. Ask client to open the xarchive file using xcode and sign the app with inhouse profile and create the ipa file
```

They have followed above instructions in 7,8 and have created the ipa file. But when we try to install the ipa file using xcode to a device it gives following error.

[image]

Does above procedure has any problem. Can some one explain the issue.

EDIT:

for testing purpose I created adhoc profile with com.mycompany.* and created an ipa file by signing above xarchive file, it gives the same error message. But If I sign the xarchive file with profile crated with com.mycompany.myapp.abc bundle id works fine.

Comment: do you have the credentials to login in to developer.apple.com ?

or do you have valid certificate with private key in ur keychain ?

Comment: Yeap. I have developer license and i have valid private key for that account in my keychain as well

Comment: in-house certificate should not use wildcard app id.

Comment: @CoolMonster Then how can I achieve above requirement.. I need to give an xarchive file so that client can sign it with enterprise license and create an ipa file

Comment: Why using wildcard app I'd in in-house provision.

Comment: @CoolMonster I have set the com.mycompany.myapp.abc as the bundle id in my xarchive file. Since I have already taken the com.mycompany.myapp.abc id, in enterprise portal they cant create profile with above id. Only option is to create an wild card id to match the com.mycompany.myapp.abc id. Otherwise client may not able to code sign the xarchive file right?

Comment: no need let them create the provision with same app id which u used to sign.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48343/discussion-between-nath-and-coolmonster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**:
Find out what the client's (provisioning profile's) entitlements are and make sure you match them.

The error is trying to say that the entitlements in your provisioning profile and their provisioning profiles differ. The difference could be a keychain group, push notification environment or something else.

The reason why Xcode asks you to choose a provisioning profile *twice* (once when archiving, once when distributing) is that all the provisioning profile entitlements are picked up in archive stage and mostly ignored in the distribution stage.

This makes it all too easy to distribute with the wrong entitlements, especially if your archive stage accidentally picked up a wildcard profile. Not your case, but that's why you should burn wildcard profiles with fire.

There are clever re-signing scripts (a.k.a. "Distribute..." button replacements) that will try to make the entitlements right by mashing what they find in the end user provisioning profile into your binary but I think the best solution is to make sure your provisioning profile's entitlements and any extra entitlements you add to your app matches their provisioning profile's.

I find Xcode's provisioning profile/entitlement system to be error prone. On hand you have entitlements that are basically part of your app's identity and may as well be set in stone (TODO: make your CI server check them). And on the other hand you have Xcode's build phase gleefully changing your app's entitlements based on its automatic/random provisioning profile selection. Silly.

Comment: As you suggested I used resigning script whit is exist in github with some changes. https://gist.github.com/Weptun/5406993

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the below step to make adhoc distribution .ipa for client

1. set bundle identifier in target info.plist
2. select the ad hoc distribution profile in target as well as in project
3. select iOS device then product-> archieve
4. organizer will pop up then select the archive and select "**distribute**" -> **Adhoc Enterprise distribution**
5. select the correct ad hoc distribution profile then save this .ipa file.
6. then send it to the client and let him know that before archiving or building the app we need correct adhoc provisioning profile . so there is no need to repeat the process at your end to set the provisioning or other stuff just distribute it .

[How to distribute your iOS app over the air:](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air)

Just need to place the .ipa file and plist on a server and set the path in the above link example.

Comment: Client dont like to give the profile to me. That's the problem. That's why i'm giving them the xarchive file so that they can create the ipa file by themselves.

Comment: Actually i don't know how could you make archive without setting provisioning profile , if there a option like that I am willing to R&D

Comment: As I mentioned in the question I have created a provisioning profile with bundle ID com.mycompany.myapp.abc and set that provisioning profile to create the .xarchive file. Is that make sense to you?

Comment: yeap i have a developer adhoc profile. I used that to create the xarchive file and ask client to use their enterprise inhouse wildcard profile to create the ipa file